# Consul quorum (3 consul servers) in Azure Kubernetes Pods

Tags: azure, kubernetes, consul, azure-aks

We have a system in an azure kubernetes cluster, consisting of 7 nodes. 3 of those nodes are consul servers, forming a quorum. We are encountering a problem, where when the pods restart, their IP address changes. Thus we are forced to re-configure the consul servers manually.
Consul is installed using the Hashicorp helm chart for our consul cluster. all of its files are stored in a persistent volume (/data) and it does store the nodeid in StatefulSet.

IF there is a way where consul can reconfigure itself or kubernetes can provide a static IP for the consul servers to connect with each other, I would appreciate it if it could be shared!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Consul on your cluster using the Hashicorp helm chart? Their architecture uses a StatefulSet for the Consul server pods and persistent volume claims to store the node-id so the pods can move around. (ref: https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/installation/overview#server-agents)

If you have used another installation method, do you have persistent volumes so the `node-id` does not change between restarts? Please expand on your Consul installation method, current configuration and re-configuration steps that are required as well.

Comment: Consul is installed using the Hashicorp helm chart for our consul cluster. All of its files are stored in a persistent volume (/data) and it does store the nodeid in StatefulSet. However, the problem we encounter is that when a pod is restarted, and has a different IP, we have to manually change it in all of the consul nodes, so that they can connect.

Comment: What value do you have for settings `leave_on_terminate` and `autopilot.cleanup_dead_servers`? (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940751/4601453) 
Do you have any logs that show the error blocking the server from rejoining the cluster after IP change?